# Is it possible аdd http-header x-accel-expires in add_view, add_static_view from Pyramid?

Tags: python, http-headers, pyramid

I'm need opportunity to add http-header(X-Accel-Expires) for each add_view.
And for add_static_view.
Ideally would be pass parameter, something like add_view(..., x_accel_expires=100), add_static_view(...,  x_accel_expires=100), but the pyramid can't this.

I can do Base View, where add http-header X-Accel-Expires.
I will only need to add an attribute in each view, something like: add_headers = (('X-Accel-Expires', '100'),).

But how can add this header for add_static_view?

Answer (score 1):

For the case of `add_view` you can use the `decorator` argument as documented by [view configuration parameters](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/narr/viewconfig.html#view-configuration-parameters):

> A dotted Python name to a function (or the function itself) which will be used to decorate the registered view callable. The decorator function will be called with the view callable as a single argument. The view callable it is passed will accept (context, request). The decorator must return a replacement view callable which also accepts (context, request). The decorator may also be an iterable of decorators, in which case they will be applied one after the other to the view, in reverse order.

This is the example given in the documentation:

```
@view_config(..., decorator=(decorator2, decorator1))
def myview(request):
   pass
```

Is similar to doing:

```
@view_config(...)
@decorator2
@decorator1
def myview(request):
   pass
```

This would allow you to write the following for example:

```
def accel_headers_factory(expires=100):
    def add_accel_headers(view):
       def wrapped_view(context, request):
           resp = view(context, request)
           resp.headers.append(('X-Accel-Expires', expires))
       return wrapped_view
    return add_accel_headers
```

Then use:

```
@view_config(..., decorator=(accel_headers_factory(500),))
def myview(request):
    return {}
```

This would then always add the `X-Accel-Expires` header to the response as returned from the view.

---

Unfortunately it doesn't look like `add_static_view` allows you to pass it a decorator argument.